# Changing ”Homepage” menu text to ”Home” Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I'm using the Storefront theme.

I have the menu:

Homepage,
Menu,
My account,
Checkout,
etc.

But instead of Homepage, I want it to say just "Home".

I tried modifying this from WP Admin -> Pages -> Edit page.

Changing the title to "Home" does not work. Weirdly, it displays as "Home" in WP Admin, but as "Homepage" in Storefront (WooCommerce).

As per page settings:

```
Title: Home
Parent: Homepage (no parent)
Order: 0
Template: Default template
```

Comment: I don't find this in the theme Storefront. look in the menu configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appearance > Menus > click to [image] > change "Navigation Label"

Comment: I deleted my cache after trying your solution and it works. Thank you!